# SVM formulation

Tags: svm

Here is an extract of an article. They are solving a One Vs  One classification problem.

What does "y" stands for ? It is a bias ?

The way they are expressing the minimization problem is quite confusing...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this formulation $\gamma$ serves as the bias term. This form is equivalent to adding on an extra dimension to $x$ where the value in that dimension is always $-1$.

$y$ is in fact an error vector - it represents how far the classification of each point is from the desired value of $1$. Note that since $y$ contributes as $||y||^2$ to the objective, this formulation is actually trying to find $w$ and $\gamma$ as a regression - where points in $A+$ should be $1$ and points in $A-$ should be $-1$, and the loss is symmetric for each class around those value. For classification one would generally have a hinge-loss (or similar).

Comment: So that means this formulation will try to avoid points too well classified (too big values of points in A+ per instance) ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.